# обьясните как работает

Tags: java

есть метод,помогите пожалуйста понять,как он работает

```
public static int process(int[][] data) throws InterruptedException {
        final AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(0);
        final Thread[] p = new Thread[data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            final int[] r = data[i];
            p[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                for (int s0 = 0; s0 < r.length - 1; s0++) {
                    final int s1 = s0 + 1;
                    if (r[s0] > r[s1]) {
                        final int tmp = r[s0];
                        r[s0] = r[s1];
                        r[s1] = tmp;
                        c.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                }
            });
            p[i].start();
        }
        for (Thread t : p) {
            t.join();
        }
        return c.get();
    }
```

я не совсем понимаю,некоторые строки,точнее этот кусок,что он делает и можно ли переписать без лямбды

```
p[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                for (int s0 = 0; s0 < r.length - 1; s0++) {
                    final int s1 = s0 + 1;
                    if (r[s0] > r[s1]) {
                        final int tmp = r[s0];
                        r[s0] = r[s1];
                        r[s1] = tmp;
                        c.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                }
```

для чего прибавлять+1 в этой строке

```
 final int s1 = s0 + 1;
```

и что делает эта часть?

```
c.incrementAndGet();
```

спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начну с конца.

Ваша строка `c.incrementAndGet();` согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--) увеличивает текущее значение `c` и берет его значение, равносильно записям с обычным int, например, как

```
int c=0;
System.out.println(++c);
```

Атомик используется, так как у вас многопоточное (Thread) приложение и вам нужны объекты, которые не смогут быть изменены другими потоками в то время как 1 какой-то поток уже обращается к переменной этого объекта.

Строка `final int s1 = s0 + 1;` создает переменную `s1` которая не должна быть измененной во время работы программы в области ее объявляения, то есть внутри `for(;;)`.

Почему столько много переменных, может объяснить [этот](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/dvumernye-massivy-v-java/) сайт. Потому что у вас двумерный массив и вам нужно пройтись по всем его элементам.

Например, у вас будет так

```
 int[][] data={{1,2,3},{2,3,4}};
```

Вы сначала должны, но не обязаны, пробежаться по строкам, которая будет содержать столбцы. В данном случае, у вас 2 строки с 3 столбцами.

В вашем цикле вы создаете

```
 final Thread[] p = new Thread[data.length];
```

массив потоков размером равным количеству строк. В моем примере это 2
Потом вы бежите по каждой строке и

```
 final int[] r = data[i];
```

создаете массив `r` который будет равен количеству ваших столбцов. В моем примере их 3.

После этого, для каждого столбца, это видно по строчке

```
for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
```

вы создаете новый поток ( Thread ) через лямбду, внутри которого вы делаете что-то, а именно

```
for (int s0 = 0; s0 < 3 - 1; s0++) {
    final int s1 = 0 + 1;
    if (r[0] > r[1]) {
    final int tmp = r[0];
    r[0] = r[1];
    r[1] = tmp;
    c.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Всё это можно делать как

```
Thread newThread= new Thread(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               for (int s0 = 0; s0 < r.length - 1; s0++) {
                                   int s1 = s0 + 1;
                                   if (r[s0] > r[s1]) {
                                       final int tmp = r[s0];
                                       r[s0] = r[s1];
                                       r[s1] = tmp;
                                       c.incrementAndGet();
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       });
p[i] = newThread;
```

Этот пример, насколько я понял, иллюстрирует сортировку выбором. О сортировках можно посмотреть [тут](http://study-java.ru/uroki-java/urok-11-sortirovka-massiva/)